# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '_'

Tags: java, printf

The problem is `Conversion = "_"`. The source code is here. I tried to read a txt and its ok! Then the code "tokenize" the words and its ok too. But when I try to save in another txt I get this error.

But if I DELETE "__" it save successfully but I don't want to delete "_"!

This is a program used for tokenize some words.

I just want to know what I should do in that line. Or what I can do to run my project without this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '_'
    at cugru.test.main(test.java:81)
```

At line 81!!

Here is the code:

```
package cugru;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.cogroo.analyzer.Analyzer;
import org.cogroo.analyzer.ComponentFactory;
import org.cogroo.text.Document;
import org.cogroo.text.impl.DocumentImpl;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("D:/Felipe/Downloads/eclipse/workspace/java worskpace luna/Excel java/sumarios/gold sem tokens.txt"));      
        BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(reader); 
        String linha = null; 
        int contadorTokens = 0;
        FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("d:\\tabuada.txt");
        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);   

        //Cria procedimentos padrao do CoGrOO
        ComponentFactory factory = ComponentFactory.create(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        Analyzer cogroo = factory.createPipe();


        int qtde = 0;

        while((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null) { 

            qtde++;
            if(qtde >10)
                break;

            //linha = linha.toLowerCase(); //deixa em minusculo

            //System.out.println(linha);
            linha = expandirAcronimos(linha);
            //System.out.println(linha);
            //System.out.println("======================================");


            /** for (int i = 0; i < sentenca.length; i++) {

                    sentenca = linha.split(" ");// separa a "linha" emdentro das aspas) e joga para o array sentenca
//              System.out.println(sentenca[i]);ido acetil saliclico ");
//              System.out.println(sentenca[i]);
                    sentenca[i] = sentenca[i].replace(" AAS "," ido acetil saliico ");
                }**/
            Document document = new DocumentImpl();
            document.setText(linha);

            cogroo.analyze(document);

            for (org.cogroo.text.Sentence sentence : document.getSentences()) { // lista de sentencas



                sentence.getStart(); sentence.getEnd(); // caracteres onde a sentenca comeca e termina
                String texto_sentenca = sentence.getText(); // texto da sentenca
                //Imprime sentenca
                //System.out.println(texto_sentenca);



                // Tokens
                for (org.cogroo.text.Token token : sentence.getTokens()) { // lista de tokens
                    token.getStart(); token.getEnd(); // caracteres onde o token comeca e termina
                    token.getLexeme(); // o texto do token (palavra que ele separa e pega exp: "clinico"
                    token.getLemmas(); // um array com os possiveis lemas para o par lexeme+postag
                    token.getPOSTag(); // classe morfologica de acordo com o contexto("coloca "prp, adj,n(noun))
                    token.getFeatures(); // genero, numero, tempo etc
                    contadorTokens++;
                    System.out.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());// imprime a palavra com o tag
                      gravarArq.printf(token.getLexeme() + "__" + token.getPOSTag() + "__" + token.getFeatures());
                    //System.out.println(token.getLexeme());
                }




                //System.out.println("Total de tokens sao: "+contadorTokens);
            }  

        }



        reader.close(); 
        arq.close();  


    }




}
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this post.

Comment: *"why i need to write a lot and stackoverflow dont let me post the question? "* Because this is our house, and in our house we expect you to read and follow [our rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i know... but i had to delete somethings to stackoverflow let me post that.. can you help me? i'm getting that error in line 81 is it:  gravarArq.printf(token.getLexeme() + "__" + token.getPOSTag() + "__" + token.getFeatures());

Comment: What do you expect it to output? And why are you calling `printf()`?

Comment: hmmmm i'm calling printf because i saw in a exemple for save in txt with printf for java.. and i'm trying to do the same XDD hahaha can i use other type ? i expected to show in my txt like "Quirino_n_M" is an exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `printf()` is not the same as `println()`. It is used for formatted output. The first parameter is a string that formats the characters. For example:

```
System.out.printf( "%2d %2d%n", x, y );
```

But you used the thing that you wanted to print as the first argument. The method thinks this is a format string, and looks for parts that begin with `%`. You probably have `%` in your string, but after it there is an `_`. This is not a legal format, so you get this exception.

You probably wanted to use the `println()` method. Using it would eliminate the exception.

Comment: lol man, i'm a dumbass!!! HAHAHAHA thanks you a lot, you are the man!!  i love you ... its basic like that? it works now! thanks ALOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

you use from printf!

```
 gravarArq.printf(token.getLexeme() + "__" + token.getPOSTag() + "__" + token.getFeatures());
```

You must define a format for your printf method
for more information :

[link here](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm)

Comment: Rather than providing a link, you should summarize the relevant information that addresses OP's problem. As it stands, this post should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: hmmm i read that... so than i need to use %c because i have "_" a char in my printf right? but where i need to put that %c?